# What is the correct way to represent 2D Vectors in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, vector

I see some options: you can use a list, you can use a vector, you can use tuples, you can use a custom datatype with a `x` and a `y` field, etc. In most languages, one way is preferred against another for some specific reasons. For example, in C++, it is much more performant to use a class.

Which is considered the linguistic way to do it in Haskell?

Comment: To represent a single vector (or point) use a data type - you probably want strictness on the x and y fields so using a pair (tuple) is not the best option as it is non-strict in its data.

Comment: @stephentetley why I want strictness?

Comment: Viclib - for performance. It makes sense to keep the Vec polymorphic in its element for x and y, but most likely you will be using Doubles to represent them. If you know you'll be working with unboxed scalar types like Doubles or Ints you want GHC to compile to optimized prim ops when you manipulate them. (Editted)

Comment: "in C++, it is much more performant to use a class" that's not true, nor is something equivalent true in Haskell. In C++, it's fastest to make as much use of inlining / vectorisation optimisation tricks, which as it happens can quite well be done with class objects on the stack. Still sometimes it can be benefitial to have C-style arrays instead, to be able to write an optimised version of some new operation you don't want to be a class method.

Answer (score 4):

The `V2` type from the `linear` package (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.16.2/docs/Linear-V2.html) is both performant and has a whole bunch of standard operations defined around it.

Comment: I love it and is what I use now (notice I asked the question 2 years ago :P). I  just wish it was more documented (following types is good, but what if you don't know where to look for a function?)... and that the Gloss package was compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly implement N-d vectors with `UArray`, since such arrays are strict and it let me combine arrays of different norms. I even have an extension (actually a class `Vector` that generalizes euclidian vectors) that lets me add matrices support.